# how to fix a missing return statement error in java

Tags: java

I'm making a code for a madlibs game and the compiler keeps saying that I am missing a return statement at the very end of the method. How do I fix this?

```
public static String getNextStep (Scanner scan, String prompt)
   { 
      boolean go = true;    
      System.out.print(prompt);
      String filename;
      if (scan.hasNext())
      {
         while (go)
         {
            filename = scan.next();
            if (((filename.toLowerCase()).equals('c'))||((filename.toLowerCase()).equals('v')))
               return filename;
            else if ((filename.toLowerCase()).equals('q'))
            {
               System.out.print("Thanks for playing!"); 
               go = false;
               return null;
            }
            else 
            {
               System.out.print(prompt);
               return null;
            }
         }
      }
      else 
         return null;
   }
```

Comment: The real question is why do you have a while loop

Comment: you should remove ```else```

Answer (score 1):

Change that final

```
else
    return null;
```

to

```
return null;
```

I have not validated your algorithm in any way. But a `String` will never equal a `char`. So, this

```
if (((filename.toLowerCase()).equals('c'))||((filename.toLowerCase()).equals('v')))
```

should be

```
if (((filename.toLowerCase()).equals("c"))||((filename.toLowerCase()).equals("v")))
```

and

```
else if ((filename.toLowerCase()).equals('q'))
```

should be

```
else if ((filename.toLowerCase()).equals("q"))
```

for the same reason.